# Adding a parent Node to an XML with Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, nodes

I need to insert a parent node to my existing XML. I have found examples of how to add child nodes to a parent node but nothing on adding a new root node to an xml. 
My source XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Make>Hyundai</Make>
        <Model>Accent</Model>
        <Year>2016</Year>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Mitsubishi</Make>
        <Model>Mirage</Model>
        <Year>2016</Year>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Ford</Make>
        <Model>Fiesta</Model>
        <Year>2017</Year>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

and my new XML should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<List_Wrappers>
    <Cars>
        <Car>
            <Make>Hyundai</Make>
            <Model>Accent</Model>
            <Year>2016</Year>
        </Car>
        <Car>
            <Make>Mitsubishi</Make>
            <Model>Mirage</Model>
            <Year>2016</Year>
        </Car>
        <Car>
            <Make>Ford</Make>
            <Model>Fiesta</Model>
            <Year>2017</Year>
        </Car>
    </Cars>
</List_Wrappers>
```

I am new to groovy.I mean to do something like this:

```
class Test {
    static stringXML = "C:/Users/xyz/original.xml"

    static main(args) {

        def baseXML = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File(stringXML))         
        baseXML.cars.parent.appendNode('List_Wrapper')        
        def writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/xyz/updated.xml")
        groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( baseXML,writer )      
    }
}
```

However, the tag is not getting added, but my modified XML turns out to be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tag0:Cars>
    <tag0:Car>
        <tag0:Make>Hyundai</tag0:Make>
        <tag0:Model>Accent</tag0:Model>
        <tag0:Year>2016</tag0:Year>
    </tag0:Car>
    <tag0:Car>
        <tag0:Make>Mitsubishi</tag0:Make>
        <tag0:Model>Mirage</tag0:Model>
        <tag0:Year>2016</tag0:Year>
    </tag0:Car>
    <tag0:Car>
        <tag0:Make>Ford</tag0:Make>
        <tag0:Model>Fiesta</tag0:Model>
        <tag0:Year>2017</tag0:Year>
    </tag0:Car>
</tag0:Cars>
```

Need help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in your code:

`baseXML.cars.parent.appendNode('List_Wrapper')`

- `Cars` is your root node.You can't put it this `baseXML.Cars`.
- you can't make `root.parent`

Try this code, It will satisfy your requirement,

```
def newXml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {

List_Wrapper {

    mkp.yield baseXML

    }
}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(newXml)
```

**Update 1 :**

Use `XmlParser()` Like shown below, 
 `def baseXML = new XmlParser().parse(new File(stringXML))` to avoid `tag0` problems.

(or)

Modify : 
`def baseXML = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(new File(stringXML).getText())`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The List_Wrapper node got added successfully. But I also don't want to change anything else in the XML apart from adding the root node. However, currently the prefix 'tag0' is getting added to my XML and is modifying the whole XML. How do I avoid that?

Comment: @SayantaniRoyChaudhuri Use `XmlParser()` to parse xml for avoiding that `tag0` problems.

Comment: @SayantaniRoyChaudhuri If you realize this answer solves your problem, It should be accepted as answer and also eligible for an upvote. Learn https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. I tried it out and it is working well.